# Is Stripe Checkout leaking memory?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks, stripe-payments

The issue I'm seeing is that when you load [Stripe Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom) into a page using their canonical "Custom" guide, configure it, and then open and close it a few times, the browser memory usage continually jumps. It sometimes, sorta gets released a little, but the residual always grows. And on a long lived page/SPA, eventually things crawl.

1. Start Google Chrome with `--enable-precise-memory-info` flag (issue happens with or without this flag)
2. Copy the "Custom" example on their site: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom (or use your own setup, the results are the same).
3. Click the 'Purchase' button (or trigger your `stripeInstance.open(cfg)`), fiddle with the popup, close.
4. Repeat step 3, watch memory gradually

You can watch memory with [memory-stats.js](https://github.com/paulirish/memory-stats.js) or just by running in (Chrome) console:

```
performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize
```

I'm convinced this has to be "me" and not Stripe. No way they'd leak so bad on `open` and `close` events right?

---

Edit: Here's a JS fiddle that literally copies their demo code: https://jsfiddle.net/p1Lfuewt/

And a 5 second interval screen shot of memory with basically just opening and closing their widget by clicking "purchase" (no idea what that promise error is, that's them):

[image: Memory leak]

Comment: Can you maybe include a jsfiddle with the issue? It'd be easier to debug this way.

Comment: @kichik here's the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/p1Lfuewt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, yes.

The longer answer is, it sure *seems* like it. The attached [JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/p1Lfuewt/) replicates the [Stripe canonical docs](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#integration-custom), and it's trivial to replicate the issue of memory blowing out on the simple act of opening and closing Stripe's widget.

```
handler.open({
  name: 'Stripe.com',
  description: '2 widgets',
  zipCode: true,
  amount: 2000
})
// Repeat for
```

A (terrible) workaround we implemented was tracking the number of opens+closes events and forcing a hard reload after X events for edge cases reaching those levels.

Comment: Have you reported it as a bug already? If yes, please link the issue, if no, please do it.

Comment: @Bergi any idea where to do that? https://github.com/stripe has nothing for Checkout (which is not listed on their open source site), and the Checkout website has no mechanism for feedback that I can find.

Comment: Ok, that is bad support. I could only find https://support.stripe.com/ which mentions an IRC channel for devs

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/checkout#what-browsers-does-checkout-support mentions the generic email contact

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to know for sure, but they could be retaining some data that it is never freed or it could be chrome's java script engine that try to have everything cached for the future. You should try to leave the page alone some time and see if the cache memory goes down.

Comment: Yes, this is sort of the definition of a memory leak. Thanks for your suggestion (our tests show the memory does not come down by much even after a while). Feel free to test yourself https://jsfiddle.net/p1Lfuewt/

Comment: I wanted to say that perhaps is not only stripes fault.